# Exclude cases with blank recordtypes in process builder

Tags: process-builder, record-type, null, isblank

I am trying to exclude cases with blank record type on the process builder that I've built, the process should not trigger a flow for cases with certain recordtypes and for cases with blank record types. I am trying to exclude cases with few record types and blank record types
Please advise. Here are two different variations I tried.

1.
OR(

[Case].RecordType.DeveloperName <> 'X',
[Case].RecordType.DeveloperName <> 'Y',
[Case].RecordType.DeveloperName <> Null

)

2.
OR(

[Case].RecordType.DeveloperName <> 'X',
[Case].RecordType.DeveloperName <> 'Y',
[Case].RecordType.DeveloperName <>'',
)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you have cases with a blank record type?  When you have record types on an object, all new records are required to have a record type.

Comment: We have a Chat bot that creates cases without recordtype

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
OR(
[Case].RecordType.DeveloperName <> "X", [Case].RecordType.DeveloperName <> "Y", [Case].RecordType.DeveloperName <> "" )
```